# Excel VBA using Combobox with Index Match

Tags: vba, indexing, match

I have an Excel VBA UserForm Combobox for scanning asset tags to compare against a site baseline held in Sheet1. There can be upto 50,000+ assets. The named ranges are all correct.

I want the loop to fill the "Found" Asset attribute Textboxes for Type, Serial, MakeModel, Location & PrinterHost.

The code is below without the additional index match lookups for extra asset attributes as the process will be the same. Help appreciated as I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub ComboScanTag_Change()

Dim x As Integer
Dim AssetCount As Long
Dim BASELINE As Range
Dim AssetID As Range
Dim FoundType As Variant
Dim FoundSerial As Variant
Dim FoundMakeModel As Variant
Dim FoundLocation As Variant
Dim FoundPrinterHostName As Variant

If Me.ComboScanTag.Value = "" Then                                      'ScanTag has no value
MsgBox "Asset not Found - Re-Scan or enter New Asset details"
Me.ComboScanTag.SetFocus
End If
If Me.ComboScanTag.Value <> "" Then                                     'ScanTag has a value
Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                      'Turn off screen updating to speed app
For x = 1 To AssetCount                                                 'Number of loop iterations from Baseline Assets Count D1 cell
    FoundType = Application.Index("BASELINE", Application.Match(Me.ComboScanTag.Value, "AssetID", False), 3)
        If Not IsError(FoundType) = False Then                          'if error value in lookup return 0
            Me.txtFoundType.Value = FoundType                           'Fill textbox FoundType with lookup value from baseline
        Else
    On Error GoTo 0                                                         'reset error handler
FoundSerial = Application.Index("BASELINE", Application.Match(Me.ComboScanTag.Value, "AssetID", False), 11)
    If Not IsError(FoundSerial) = False Then
Me.txtFoundSerial.Value = FoundSerial

    End If
Next x
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AssetCount` is not initialized. You need to initialize it before you use it like `AssetCount = 10`.
`BASELINE` and `AssetID` are not set as well.

If `BASELINE` and `AssetID` are named ranges, you cannot use it the way you do in `Application.Index` or Application.Match.
You need to pass it as object and not as string like this:

```
Set BASELINE = ThisWorkbook.Names("BASELINE").RefersToRange
Set AssetID = ThisWorkbook.Names("AssetID").RefersToRange
```

Then you can use it like this in `Application.Index` and `Match`:

```
With Application
    FoundType = .Index(BASELINE, .Match(Me.ComboScanTag.Value, AssetID, False), 3)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge - this has helped me a lot as most of the threads I've seen do not mention passing as objects when using index and match to perform lookups in VBA